# How many integers $\leq N$ are divisible by $2,3$ but not divisible by their powers?

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

How many integers in the range $\leq N$ are divisible by both $2$ and $3$ but are not divisible by whole powers $>1$ of $2$ and $3$  i.e. not divisible by  $2^2,3^2, 2^3,3^3, \ldots ?$

I hope by using the inclusion–exclusion principle one may derive such a formula and part of the formula has a form 
$$
N-\left[\frac{N}{2} \right]+\left[\frac{N}{2^2} \right]-\left[\frac{N}{2^3} \right]+\cdots -\left[\frac{N}{3} \right]+\left[\frac{N}{3^2} \right]-\left[\frac{N}{3^3} \right]+\cdots+\left[\frac{N}{2 \cdot 3} \right]+\text{some terms like as $\pm \left[\frac{N}{2^i \cdot 3^j} \right]$}
$$

**Question.** What is the exact sign for a term $ \left[\frac{N}{2^i \cdot 3^j} \right]$?

Comment: One tip is to try it for $2$ alone first. Also note that asking about divisibility by $8$ or $16$ is irrelevant. You want the numbers that are divisible by $2$, but not $4$, and that's it.

Comment: You should replace $i$ with $\lfloor{\log_2N}\rfloor$ and $j$ with $\lfloor{\log_3N}\rfloor$. You should use two separate terms there IMO (i.e., $\frac{N}{2^i}$ and $\frac{N}{3^j}$). And the sign of these terms should be $(-1)^i$ and $(-1)^j$ respectively.

Comment: For 2 we can use binary representation. We need to count the representations that have 0 as the units digit and 1 as the next digit. Hence up to $2^n$, there are $2^{n-2}$ numbers that are divisible by 2 but not by any other power of 2. For example up to 8, we have 2 numbers: 2, 6.

Comment: I'm a little confused by the question. Do you want all numbers $\le N$ divisible by $6$ but not any other numbers of the form $2^i3^j$ (for $i,j > 1$)?

Comment: @Leox just a heads up I edited the question to explicitly state divisible by *both* 2 *and* 3 but now i want to check you didn't mean divisible by $2$ *or* $3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to count those numbers divisible by $6=2\cdot3$, but not those divisible by $12=2^2\cdot3$ or $18=2\cdot3^2$. However, if we count both those numbers divisible by $12$ and those divisible by $18$, we've counted those divisible by $36$ twice. Therefore, the count should be
$$
\left\lfloor\frac N6\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\frac N{12}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\frac N{18}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac N{36}\right\rfloor
$$

Comment: For $N=100$, this gives $5$ for $\{6,30,42,66,78\}$.

Answer (score 3):

The rules permit all numbers divisible by $6$, but excluding those also divisble by $4$ or $9$.

This is given by:

$$\lfloor\frac{N}{6}\rfloor-\lfloor\frac{N}{12}\rfloor-\lfloor\frac{N}{18}\rfloor+\lfloor\frac{N}{36}\rfloor$$

Firstly - Start by enumerating number of numbers divisible by 6.

Next term: Remove numbers divisible by 6 and 4. These are all numbers divisible by 12 since the intersection of prime factors is $3\times2^2$

Next term: Remove numbers divisible by 6 and 9. These are all numbers divisible by 18 since the intersection of prime factors is $2\times3^2$

Next term: Add back in the multiples of 36 since these are the numbers we have deducted twice; divisible by 6, 4, and 9. Intersection of prime factors is $2^2\times3^2$.

Comment: Sorry my bad, it says $<N$ so I think I should have $N-1$ in place of $N$.

Comment: Hang on the title doesn't match the question!!!!  I will edit.

Comment: Ok I fixed the $<$ in the title to $\leq$ to match the question.

Comment: for $N=100$ yours formula gives $-18$

Comment: Asymptotically, this formula gives $\sim-\frac N6$

Comment: @Leox haha!  Good point.

Comment: @Leox ok fixed. I will add text to explain.

Comment: @robjohn How's it looking now?

Comment: Since it now matches my answer, what can I say?

Comment: @robjohn clearly I'm standing on the shoulders of giants.